# MySQL How to dynamically choose which table to get data from when creating a view

Tags: mysql, view

I'm a student with very little experience with SQL. I'm trying to collect data from multiple different tables and gather the relevant information into a single view in MySQL. Problem is the structuring of the query is way too complicated for my skills and honestly I'm not even sure if it's possible to do this the way I'm trying to.

Here is the basic structure of the tables I'm trying to use here(names changed):
**Product_product_attribute**: product_id, product_attribute_id, value

**Product_attribute:** id, name

**Material:** id, name

**Same structure as Material is basically then repeated for 4 other attribute type tables for example Color table**

So I need to create a query that will display product_id, the name of the attribute, and the explanation for its value in a view. The name is fetched from the Product_attribute table based on id, but the explanation for the value is fetched from one of the 5 attribute tables based on the value given and what the product_attribute_id is.

So for example product 1 has attribute 1 and the value of the attribute is 3, so first we identify what attribute is in question by the product_attribute_id (in this case it's material) and then we have to go to the material table to see what the value '3' means (let's say it means steel). Then this is repeated for every attribute the product has and for every product.

But how do I make a query that is capable of fetching the explanation for the value from 5 different tables based on the product_attribute_id?

Here's how far I got when thinking about this if you want to see, even though it's nowhere near correct (also it obviously only tries to get material attributes value explanation because I had no idea how to even start getting all the others):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW allattributesview AS

SELECT t1.product_id, t2.name, (SELECT m.name
        FROM product_product_attribute t LEFT JOIN material m  ON t.value = m.id 
        WHERE t.value = m.id) 
FROM product_product_attribute t1 LEFT JOIN product_attribute t2 ON t1.product_attribute_id = t2.id
WHERE t1.product_attribute_id = t2.id
```

I think I need to use the CASE clause but I don't have any idea where to put it or how to format it. Please help.

EDIT:

Sample data:

**Product_product_attribute**

```
product_id  product_attribute_id  value
1           1                     3
1           2                     4
1           4                     1
2           1                     2
```

**Product_attribute:**

```
id  name

1   Material
2   Color
3   Some
4   Other
5   Attributes
```

**Material**

```
id  name

1   Steel
2   Silver
3   Wood
```

**Color**

```
id  name
1   Red
2   Blue
3   Green
4   Yellow
```

Same style repeats for the other 3 attribute tables

The result I want to accomplish:

```
product_id  name      value

1           Material  Wood
1           Color     Yellow
```

etc.

I hope this helped to make my poorly formatted question somewhat clearer.

Comment: It's not clear to me how your data hangs together. You seem to be saying that there are potentially 5 material tables that relate to (potentially) 5 rows in Product_product_attribute (1 of each product/attribute) but you have no idea which material table to look at. It would help if you could add sample data and expected result as text to the question or sqlfiddle

Comment: @P.Salmon Thanks, I edited it. To clarify there are exactly 5 different TYPES of attributes (such as material, color etc.) and they each have their own table which explains the meaning of the 'value' for each different type of attribute. I know it's confusing, I hardly understand how it works myself ( I didn't make the database).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not convinced about your design and this solution 'denormalises' to get to a point where a simple join from the first table spits out the correct result , I think - note I have one more result in my result set than you.

```
CREATE TABLE Product_product_attribute (product_id INT, product_attribute_id  INT, value INT);
INSERT INTO Product_product_attribute VALUES
(1  ,         1 ,                    3),
(1  ,         2 ,                    4),
(1  ,         4 ,                    1),
(2  ,         1 ,                    2);

CREATE TABLE Product_attribute(id INT, name VARCHAR(20));
INSERT INTO Product_attribute VALUES
(1  , 'Material'),
(2  , 'Color'),
(3  , 'Some'),
(4  , 'Other'),
(5  , 'Attributes');

CREATE TABLE Material (id INT, name VARCHAR(20));
INSERT INTO MATERIAL VALUES
(1  , 'Steel'),
(2  , 'Silver'),
(3  , 'Wood');

CREATE TABLE Color(id INT, name VARCHAR(20));
INSERT INTO COLOR VALUES
(1 ,  'Red'),
(2 ,  'Blue'),
(3 ,  'Green'),
(4 ,  'Yellow');

 select ppa.*,b.*
FROM Product_product_attribute PPA
join
(
select id, name ,a.*
from    Product_attribute PA 
join
(
select 'material' attribute, id attributeid, name attributevalue from material
union 
select 'color' attribute, id, name from color
) a
on a.attribute = pa.name
) b
on b.id = ppa.product_attribute_id AND b.attributeid = ppa.value
order by ppa.product_id, ppa.product_attribute_id,ppa.value
```

Result

```
+------------+----------------------+-------+------+----------+-----------+-------------+----------------+
| product_id | product_attribute_id | value | id   | name     | attribute | attributeid | attributevalue |
+------------+----------------------+-------+------+----------+-----------+-------------+----------------+
|          1 |                    1 |     3 |    1 | Material | material  |           3 | Wood           |
|          1 |                    2 |     4 |    2 | Color    | color     |           4 | Yellow         |
|          2 |                    1 |     2 |    1 | Material | material  |           2 | Silver         |
+------------+----------------------+-------+------+----------+-----------+-------------+----------------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```